# Is there anyway for adding graphql api with postgres data source using aws amplify CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

You can change the data source of `appsync` service in aws console, but I am not sure if it can work after I run command
 `amplify push api`
 And haven't found a way of changing data source with `aws-amplify`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way, no, as AppSync doesn't have native Postgres data sources. You could theoretically do anything with a Lambda data source, though, very much including Postgres.

An AppSync dev created a sample app that shows a way to do this, via what Amplify calls custom resolvers. You can find that repo here: https://github.com/mikeparisstuff/amplify-cli-nested-api-sample